# Removing objects from a queryset by ID optimal implementation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `queryset` of `1000000` objects `MyModel`.
All objects in `queryset` have an `ID`.

I pass a list of ids to remove, for example:

```
ids = ['1', '23', '117', ...] # len = 100000
```

Then, i need to delete objects in `queryset` with `ids`.

List of `ids` can contains non-existent ids.

What is the best way to do it?

My variant:

```
for id in ids:
    obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id)
    if obj:
        obj.delete()
```

I'm not sure about it, because it will make a `100000` queries to the database, maybe it makes sense to convert the `queryset` to a `list`, then filter it by `id`?

On the other hand, if there are a million objects in the database, and only one needs to be deleted, this will create an inverse relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current approach will query the database `1000000` times, you can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)
lookup and do bulk deletion by applying `delete()` just after `filter()`:

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).delete()
```

Now the database would be affected only one time.

### Edit:

To filter all the valid IDs in optimal way do intersection in the following way:

```py
all_existing_ids = set(MyModel.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True))
all_valid_ids = set(ids) & existing_ids
```